# Most Recent Record from two different databases

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

**THANKS TO A PREVIOUS COMMENT POINTING OUT A SEQUENCING ERROR, THIS QUERY EXAMPLE HAS BEEN UPDATED, BUT THE PROBLEM HAS NOT BEEN SOLVED**

I have two databases, Lets call them db1 and db2. Each database has a table with the patient's name and a table with the patient's test record. I am trying to retrieve the most recent test record between both databases. The only common factor between the two databases, and what I'm using as the unique identifier, is the first Initial, Last name and DOB.

The code as is will give me the unique number of records by the maximum test date. My problem is that if I comment in the test_ID or test_results then I will receive duplicates. I tried joining the tables again and trying a CASE statement, but for each record, it will pull more than one test_id (only returns a few duplicates) or if I comment in the case statement for Test_results (returns about double the records back).I want to avoid joining group1. I am using TSQL/Microsoft SQL analyzer 2000

my query looks something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT group1.LastName
                , group1.firstInitial
                , group1.DOB
                , MAX(group1.Test_date) AS Max_test_date
                -- , CASE WHEN g.Test_id IS NULL then h.Test_id 
                --        else g.Test_id 
                --        end
                -- , CASE WHEN g.Test_result IS NULL then h.Test_result
                --        else g.Test_result
                --        end
FROM(
   SELECT DISTINCT a.lastname AS LastName
                , left(a.firstname, 1) AS 'firstInitial'
                , a.dob
                , b.resultsdb1 AS Test_result
                , b.test_datedb1 AS Test_date
                , b.Lab_iddb1 AS test_id
   FROM db1.patient a
   JOIN db1.testrec b ON b.patient_ID = a.patient_ID
                         AND b.test_date = (SELECT MAX(b1.test_date)
                                             FROM db1.testrec b1
                                             WHERE b1.patient_ID = b.patient_ID
                         AND b.test_id = (SELECT MAX(b1.test_id)
                                             FROM db1.testrec b1
                                             WHERE b1.patient_ID = b.patient_ID)
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT c.lastname AS LastName
                , left(c.firstname, 1) AS 'firstInitial'
                , c.dob
                , d.resultsdb2 AS Test_result
                , d.test_datedb2 AS Test_date
                , d.Lab_iddb2 AS test_id
   FROM db2.patient c
   JOIN db2.testrec d ON d.patient_ID = c.patient_ID
                         AND d.test_date = (SELECT MAX(d1.test_date)
                                             FROM db2.testrec d1
                                             WHERE d1.patient_ID = d.patient_ID
                         AND d.test_id = (SELECT MAX(d1.test_id)
                                             FROM db2.testrec d1
                                             WHERE d1.patient_ID = d.patient_ID)
) as group1

LEFT JOIN db1.patient e ON e.Last_name = group1.lastname
                             AND left(e.firstname, 1) = group1.firstInitial
                             and e.dob = group1.dob
LEFT JOIN db2.patient f ON f.Last_name = group1.lastname
                             AND left(f.firstname, 1) = group1.firstInitial
                             and f.dob = group1.dob
LEFT JOIN db1.testrec g ON g.patient_ID = e.patient_ID
LEFT JOIN db1.testrec h ON h.patient_ID = f.patient_ID
GROUP BY group1.LastName
         , group1.firstInitial
         , group1.DOB
```

Comment: As posted this query will not run because you have a group by before your joins. You are missing at least one parenthesis on your each set of subqueries too.

Comment: Thank you. i made the correction!

Comment: Instead of case use `coalesce(g.test_ID,h.Test_ID)` and `coalesce(g.test_result, H.Test_result)`  be sure both are added the group by.  Assuming everything else works, the missing elements from the group by is the real problem, you could just repeat the case statements there; but I find coalesce more elegant in this case since all your'e checking for is a null.

Comment: Your query still has syntax errors. The subqueries starting with SELECT MAX(d1.test_date) have no closing parenthesis. As such, your comment that the code as is returns something is not accurate. The code posted here can't be the same thing you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Distinct ins't necessary with the group by
2. Coalesce to check for null is a bit cleaner than a case.
3. You're missing the cases in the group by (or did you not show them) to me this is where the problem likely is.
4. This assumes the query works otherwise.  Seems like there would be a cleaner way to write all those subqueries using a row number and partition by though.

.

```
SELECT group1.LastName
     , group1.firstInitial
     , group1.DOB
     , MAX(group1.Test_date) AS Max_test_date
     , coalesce(g.test_ID, h.test_ID)
     , coalesce(g.test_Result, H.test_Result) 
     -- , CASE WHEN g.Test_id IS NULL then h.Test_id 
     --        else g.Test_id 
     --        end
     -- , CASE WHEN g.Test_result IS NULL then h.Test_result
     --        else g.Test_result
     --        end
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT a.lastname AS LastName
          , left(a.firstname, 1) AS 'firstInitial'
          , a.dob
          , b.resultsdb1 AS Test_result
          , b.test_datedb1 AS Test_date
          , b.Lab_iddb1 AS test_id
     FROM db1.patient a
     JOIN db1.testrec b 
       ON b.patient_ID = a.patient_ID
      AND b.test_date = (SELECT MAX(b1.test_date)
                         FROM db1.testrec b1
                         WHERE b1.patient_ID = b.patient_ID
                           AND b.test_id = (SELECT MAX(b1.test_id)
                                          FROM db1.testrec b1
                                          WHERE b1.patient_ID = b.patient_ID)
     UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT c.lastname AS LastName
          , left(c.firstname, 1) AS 'firstInitial'
          , c.dob
          , d.resultsdb2 AS Test_result
          , d.test_datedb2 AS Test_date
          , d.Lab_iddb2 AS test_id
     FROM db2.patient c
     JOIN db2.testrec d 
       ON d.patient_ID = c.patient_ID
      AND d.test_date = (SELECT MAX(d1.test_date)
                         FROM db2.testrec d1
                         WHERE d1.patient_ID = d.patient_ID
                           AND d.test_id = (SELECT MAX(d1.test_id)
                                            FROM db2.testrec d1
                                            WHERE d1.patient_ID = d.patient_ID)) as group1
LEFT JOIN db1.patient e 
  ON e.Last_name = group1.lastname
 AND left(e.firstname, 1) = group1.firstInitial
 AND e.dob = group1.dob
LEFT JOIN db2.patient f 
  ON f.Last_name = group1.lastname
 AND left(f.firstname, 1) = group1.firstInitial
 AND f.dob = group1.dob
LEFT JOIN db1.testrec g 
  ON g.patient_ID = e.patient_ID
LEFT JOIN db1.testrec h 
  ON h.patient_ID = f.patient_ID
GROUP BY group1.LastName
       , group1.firstInitial
       , group1.DOB
       , coalesce(g.test_ID, h.test_ID)
       , coalesce(g.test_Result, H.test_Result) 
    -- Or comment out the 2 lines above this and un-comment out the below (be sure to change the select too)
    -- , CASE WHEN g.Test_id IS NULL then h.Test_id 
    --        else g.Test_id 
    --        end
    -- , CASE WHEN g.Test_result IS NULL then h.Test_result
    --        else g.Test_result
    --        end
```